# Limitar el tamaño de un bigint en cassandra db

Tags: base-de-datos, cassandra

Mi pregunta es simple, se puede limitar el máximo de caracteres ingresados en un bigint usando cassandra DB? En mysql uno puede usar int(10) o bigint(10), en cassandra puedo realizarlo?

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que estas en Stack Overflow, el cual a diferencia de sitios como Yahoo Respuestas, no es un sitio donde preguntes algo y esperes ayuda sin siquiera mostrar algo de codigo, algo de esfuerzo, para asi poder ayudarte, muestranos que has hecho, que errores tienes durante el proceso, muestranos el codigo, para asi poder ayudarte efectivamente.

Comment: La pregunta es absolutamente técnica y cerrada. [Cassandra DB Datatypes](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html), pero requiere que alguien con experiencia pueda aclarar las diferencias entre el mismo tipo en cassandra y mysql

Comment: @IvanBotero estoy totalmente consciente de que estoy en Stack Overflow, es una duda que nace durante el proceso de modelar una BD, no necesariamente se tiene que tener código para ello, es más técnico. Gracias de todas formas!

Answer (score 1):

No, `cassandradb` no permite establecer el tamaño de los tipo de datos `varchar`, `bigint`, `varint` como puede realizarse en `postgresql` o `mysql`

Saludos